# Python Pandas to compare two JSONs, their common subset and identify differences

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write a code in Python using Python Pandas to compare two json based on data present in the second json i.e. return true or false based on following logic -

1. First check if the json provided in second json exist and
2. If it exist then check if the value provided in second json match in the first json.
3. If the key does not exist then report the key and continue validating the remaining keys and report all the keys.

First Json:

```
{
    "header": {
        "chef":"Gordan",
        "restaurants":"petrus"
    },
    "menu":[
        {
            "starters":{
                "Isle of skye scallop":"Coastal herbs, lemon, olive oil",
                "Native Lobster":"Anjou pear, walnuts",
                "Smoked Eel":"Oscietra caviar, celeriac, apple"
            },
            "main":{
                "Cornish cod":"Heirloom carrots, pomelo",
                "Anjou Pigeon":"Beetroot, cranberry, red amaranth"
            }
        }
    ]

}
```

The second json :

```
{
    "header": {
        "chef":"Gordan"
    },
    "menu":[
        {
            "starters":{
                "Isle of skye scallop":"Coastal herbs, lemon, olive oil"
            },
            "main":{
                "Cornish cod":"Heirloom carrots, pomelo"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The code which I have written and does not work

```
import pandas as pd
import json

# First JSON
first_json = {
    "header": {
        "chef":"Gordan",
        "restaurants":"petrus"
    },
    "menu":[
        {
            "starters":{
                "Isle of skye scallop":"Coastal herbs, lemon, olive oil",
                "Native Lobster":"Anjou pear, walnuts",
                "Smoked Eel":"Oscietra caviar, celeriac, apple"
            },
            "main":{
                "Cornish cod":"Heirloom carrots, pomelo",
                "Anjou Pigeon":"Beetroot, cranberry, red amaranth"
            }
        }
    ]
}

# Second JSON
second_json = {
    "header": {
        "chef":"Gordan"
    },
    "menu":[
        {
            "starters":{
                "Isle of skye scallop":"Coastal herbs, lemon, olive oil"
            },
            "main":{
                "Cornish cod":"Heirloom carrots, pomelo"
            }
        }
    ]
}

# Convert the JSONs to pandas DataFrames
first_df = pd.json_normalize(first_json)
second_df = pd.json_normalize(second_json)

# Check if the second JSON exists in the first JSON
if second_df.isin(first_df).all().all():
    print("Second JSON exists in the first JSON.")
else:
    print("Second JSON does not exist in the first JSON.")
```

The output : Second JSON does not exist in the first JSON.

***NOTE: I am basically looking at converting both to the data-frame, then subsetting both data-frames with respect to the second data-frame as that's the smaller one (using column names), then compare both column by column and reporting pass in case equal or fail reporting which fields mismatch.***

Comment: It sounds like maybe [`jsondiff`](https://github.com/xlwings/jsondiff)  or [`jsonpatch`](https://python-json-patch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html)  could help you here instead of pandas?

Comment: Thanks @jqurious - I have used JSON for this question however, the json's I am dealing with are quite large and also I am looking for a scalable solution should the transaction traffic increases substantially. Also, this sounds like a typical use case for pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code seems to work:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import warnings


def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '.')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '.')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(y)
    return out


def check_common_columns(df1, df2):
    # convert nested JSON data to flat format
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
        df1 = json_normalize(flatten_json(df1))
        df2 = json_normalize(flatten_json(df2))

    # get common columns
    common_cols = set(df1.columns) & set(df2.columns)

    # suppress FutureWarning for passing set as an indexer
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
        df1_common = df1[list(common_cols)]
        df2_common = df2[list(common_cols)]

    # get rows with common columns that have different values
    diff_idx = (df1_common != df2_common).any(axis=1)
    df_diff = pd.concat([df1_common, df2_common])[diff_idx].drop_duplicates()

    # extract column names with different values
    col_names = list(df_diff.columns[df_diff.apply(pd.Series.nunique) > 1])

    return col_names, df_diff[col_names]


# Example JSONs
json1 = {
    "header": {
        "chef": "Gordon",
        "restaurant": "Hell's Kitchen"
    },
    "menu": [
        {
            "starters": {
                "Starter1": "Coastal herbs, lemon, olive oil",
                "Starter2": "Anjou pear, walnuts",
                "Starter3": "Oscietra caviar, celeriac, apple"
            },
            "main": {
                "main1": "Heirloom carrots, pomelo",
                "main2": "Beetroot, cranberry, red amaranth"
            }
        }
    ]
}

json2 = {
    "header": {
        "chef": "Bobby",
        "restaurant": "Bobby's Kitchen"
    },
    "menu": [
        {
            "starters": {
                "Starter1": "Coastal herbs, lemon, olive oil",
                "Starter2": "Anjou pear, walnuts",
                "Starter3": "Oscietra caviar, celeriac, apple"
            },
            "main": {
                "main1": "Heirloom carrots, pomelo",
                "main2": "Beetroot, cranberry, spinach"
            }
        }
    ]
}

col_names, diff_df = check_common_columns(json1, json2)

print("Columns with different values: ")
print(col_names)
print("\nDataframe with different values: ")
print(diff_df)
```

## Output

```
UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
  df_diff = pd.concat([df1_common, df2_common])[diff_idx].drop_duplicates()
Columns with different values: 
['header.restaurant', 'menu.0.main.main2', 'header.chef']

Dataframe with different values: 
  header.restaurant                  menu.0.main.main2 header.chef
0    Hell's Kitchen  Beetroot, cranberry, red amaranth      Gordon
0   Bobby's Kitchen       Beetroot, cranberry, spinach       Bobby
```